# Is it possible to organize sanity checks in Julia to make them easy to compile out when loading a package?

Tags: testing, julia, assert, flags, code-organization

I am developing a package that needs to run fast and be correct. I want to write just one function, but have two "versions" of this function: one that immediately stops when it detects any sort of funny business whatsoever, and another that just runs as fast as possible. My idea is to run the strict version of the function on a random sample of inputs, and provided that nothing fails, run the fast version on the entire set of inputs. I definitely don't have the computing power to run every check on every input, even though I would sleep easier if I could. (I'm open to the idea that this is already the wrong way to approach the verification problem, so if you have a better organizing approach feel free to suggest that instead of a specific improvement to below.)

So far, I've hacked up a temporary solution to this problem as follows:

```
module Foo

export some_function

const using_removeable_assertions = true

macro RemoveablyAssert(the_condition)
    if using_removeable_assertions
        return esc(:($the_condition || error("Assertion failed.")))
    else
        return esc("")
    end
end

function some_function(x::Float64,y::Float64)
    #Say this should only be called on positive numbers
    @RemoveablyAssert x>0
    @RemoveablyAssert y>0
    (x + y/2.0)::Float64
end

end

using Foo
```

So this works,

```
julia> some_function(1.0,1.0)
1.5

julia> some_function(1.0,-1.0)
ERROR: Assertion failed.
 in some_function at none:18
```

And if I reload the module where I've manually changed `const using_removeable_assertions = false`, then not only does it skip those checks,

```
julia> some_function(1.0,1.0)
1.5

julia> some_function(1.0,-1.0)
0.5
```

but in fact, as intended, the native code is identical to the same function where I never even put those lines:

```
julia> @code_native some_function(1.0,1.0)
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
Filename: none
Source line: 19
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movabsq $13174486592, %rax      ## imm = 0x31142B640
Source line: 19
    vmulsd  (%rax), %xmm1, %xmm1
    vaddsd  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

E.g. if I define

```
function some_function_2(x::Float64,y::Float64)
    (x + y/2.0)::Float64
end
```

Then

```
julia> @code_native some_function_2(1.0,1.0)
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
Filename: none
Source line: 2
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movabsq $13174493536, %rax      ## imm = 0x31142D160
Source line: 2
    vmulsd  (%rax), %xmm1, %xmm1
    vaddsd  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

So: these are two of the desired properties of a solution,

1. Turning on / off a big set of strict sanity checks should be about as simple as flipping a switch
2. In the "off" case, the native code should be completely clean of any references to the checks; in particular, there should be no
   performance difference in the off case

but I would like a solution that is a little less manual and a little more idiomatic or standard.

Note, it's impractical to manually define two versions of every function because maintaining them would be a mess. So I've thought about using another macro that generates a `some_function_safe` for each `some_function` and then just manually running the safe checks that way, but I'm hoping there's a better solution, something akin to a command line argument to `julia`, but specific to the module. E.g. `using[safemode=yes] Foo`.

Relatedly, I wonder if there's a good approach to handling multiple check "levels," beyond some similar hack e.g. defining a global "safety level" and then using macros to conditionally inject checks provided the global safety level exceeds the specific check level. If the `[safemode=yes]` idea above could be implemented, then certainly this could be implemented as well, but I'm wondering whether there's just a better way to organize these sorts of checks.

(FWIW, I consider these checks complements to, not substitutes for, a big test suite. The test suite alone doesn't make me sleep easy. Also, though my example is of argument verification, I want to use these checks not only for pre- and post-conditions but also for all sorts of sanity checks, e.g. checking invariants in bodies of methods and writing in specific checks against mistakes I've already made and fixed, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I do something fairly similar for my Julia work, I have a macro that can either be completely removed, or else if compiled in, checks a mask that I can set to control which ones are actually checked.
As far as unit testing goes, we've been use the `FactCheck.jl` package.
We plan on setting up code to do code coverage testing (we can't put our internal code on GitHub, where it would be trivial to set up), I think that is critical, along with the unit tests, to ensure reasonably good code.
If your code is on GitHub, I think adding code coverage support from either coveralls or codecov.io is trivial.

Comment: Thanks! I've looked at FactCheck too, but didn't really grok the point. What's better about `@fact [Computed Value] --> [Predicate about it]` versus `@test [Predicate about computed value]`? (Especially `@fact 1 --> is_less_than(2)` versus `@test 1 < 2`......**really??**) I agree grouping and contexts are a plus, but I expect those to end up in `Base.Test` eventually, and the other syntax bumps against my "general resistance to committing early to a 3rd-party approach that may be deprecated" inertia...,

Comment: ...,but, as we seem to have a similar approach to thinking about testing (and similar constraints re GitHub) I'm curious to hear more re: why you found `FactCheck` worth the investment. To be clear--I don't at all mean to suggest that it isn't or to criticize the hard work of the people who wrote it, just literally saying that so far I haven't seen the light re: whether it's really getting a big improvement, or just for my use case would be a little polish around the edges that I could live without given the upfront investment cost. Thx

Comment: When we started adding our own unit tests, we really liked the grouping and context features, and the way it displays both the expected value and the result. We didn't really feel there was any big upfront cost (some regex query search & replace in Emacs took care of the changes from `@test` to `@fact` pretty quickly.  If `Base.Test` ends up with those features, we'd probably move back.  We'd really prefer a unit test package that dealt with regressions though, and let us put in tests for things not yet passing.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it another look. So far my workaround to contexts is to shamelessly copy the per-file report strategy of @JohnMylesWhite et al. in `DataFrames`: https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/test/runtests.jl .